# windbg disassemble function command (uf) need some formatting

Tags: windbg

I did a uf command in windbg after attaching notepad.exe
Command was uf notepad!WinMain i got the following output

```
0:000> uf notepad!WinMain
notepad!WinMain:
0021138d mov     edi,edi
0021138f push    ebp
00211390 mov     ebp,esp
00211392 sub     esp,1Ch
00211395 push    esi
00211396 push    edi
00211397 push    6
002113c8 test    eax,eax
002113ca jl      notepad!WinMain+0x118 (00211c93)

notepad!WinMain+0x43:
002113d0 push    ebx
002113d1 push    dword ptr [ebp+14h]
002113d4 push    edi
002113d5 call    notepad!SkipProgramName (00213170)
002113e5 je      notepad!WinMain+0x10e (00211ca9)

notepad!WinMain+0x5e:
002113eb push    esi
002113ec push    esi
002113ed call    dword ptr [notepad!_imp__GetCurrentProcessId (00211084)]
```

and so on.. If you notice after every jump instruction it creates a new block like

```
002113ca jl      notepad!WinMain+0x118 (00211c93)

notepad!WinMain+0x43:
```

and at

```
002113e5 je      notepad!WinMain+0x10e (00211ca9)

notepad!WinMain+0x5e:
```

So what i wanted to know a setting in WinDbg where i can omit the creation of the new block on every jump for a function disassembly. Why can't i get the output the way i get it with U command?

So i am looking for an option like this

```
002113c8 test    eax,eax002113ca 
jl      notepad!WinMain+0x118 (00211c93)
**blank line omitted**
**notepad!WinMain+0x43:** omitted**
002113d0 push    ebx002113d1 push    dword ptr [ebp+14h]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

because function code is potentially dispersed all over your code section (up to the linker to decide where to put what and, generally, it ends up moving parts that are executed most to the top)

now, **u** does not care if you're interested in a particular function - it will simply dump the instructions sequentially, while **uf** has to look up all relevant code blocks and formats them together to make it look a whole function.

edit: unfortunately (as far as i know) there's no immediate setting for windbg to tailor for your needs - here you'll probably have to resort to some sort of post-processing (pretty-print script to remove blank lines and whatever else you need).